# bootstrap works out of control on host

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have designed a webpage which is only one navbar.
The navbar works completely fine when I am using it in my computer simulating using PHPstrom, but when I upload it to my host it start to behave badly.

Replacing the colors I gave it or combining them.

The align of flex box which I want menu to be in the middle but keep using right.

The hover effect I designed will keep overwrite by default one.

It keeps ignoring almost everything i write in my CSS and the ones it doesn't ignore, it shows half broken. None of this happens in my local server (either with xammp or PHPStorm run)

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: #242424;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/*****navbar****/

ul {
  direction: rtl;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: #242424 !important;
}

.nav-a {
  text-decoration: none;
  direction: rtl;
  justify-content: right;
  border-bottom: solid transparent 3px;
  transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.nav-a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid rgb(80, 80, 80) 3px;
}

.navbar-me {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--STYLE LINKS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title style="direction: rtl"> </title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--start Wrapper-->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!--navbar START-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-me">
      <!------------------n--------NAVToglle---------------------------------------->
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-family:monoton,sans-serif; font-size: 1.6rem; color: #e8e8e8;">Technotron</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse m-auto" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!--Unordered list----->
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto " style="justify-content: right; text-align: right;">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link nav-a" href="#">خانه</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-a" href="#">محصولات</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-a" href="#">خدمات</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link nav-a" href="#">تماس با ما</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a style=" display: inline-block; padding: 10px; background: #e8e8e8; color: #242424; text-decoration: none;" href="#"><span> فروشگاه <img src="Mainpage/pic/cart.jpg" style="width: 30px;" alt=""></span></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!--navbar STOP-->
  </div>
  <!--END Wrapper-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is `main.css` resolved on your server?

Comment: yes . the body background and half ofnavabr works . take a look technotron.ir - the picture u see is a carousel wich dose not work fine too

Comment: have you checked your console for any error? Try adding full path of your `main.css` file

Comment: not sure if characters `<!` would cause unexpected behaviour, but I believe you meant to have `<!doctype html>`

Comment: yes i did 
nothing , the console is clear . no error in fact nothing , its empty .and network in chrome shows all 200 . i refreshed 10 times got same result

Comment: @S2G can you post your host address!

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> fixed . thanks for telling me , but still having problem

Comment: http://asanwebhost.com/ is where i get my test host
technotron.ir is my test domain
is this what u are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first please check is your css file accessible on [www.your-theme-assets.com]/main.css then in browser with inspect element tools check is your theme reading you css class file? for example in firefox:

[image]

your css file may not be read correctly

or css file its been cache for test change you can you add version number end of your css file address and each time you change the css file for see new changes without caching just change number of version file in source like tihs:

themeaddress/css/style-min.css?v=2.0.4

?v=2.0.4 do nothing it just force browser read new css file

Comment: thanks shahriyar . css file dose read 
in www.technotron.ir/main.css workd
and in inspect i can see my css . but sme off them being reqrite for example bg-dark i said 242424! important but inspect said 38e7e7!important which is bootstrap color , is did not rewrite the class of bootstrap

Comment: color of my body background is right , the e8e8e8 color that i gave it but the classes which i use to overwrite bootstrap dose not work , even classes that name of them is different that the bootstrap but use be side bootstrap and try to rewrite some of the bootstrap code dose not work properly , for example there is a carousel which i wanted the background to be 242424 but it dose not show it just shows transparent background and i use the class name my-carosel in the original css file ,which is a unique name and dose not interfere with bootstrap class names

Comment: i check your background color and colors is true as you said

for example: .bg-dark {
    background-color: #242424 !important;
} 

its run correctly

maybe its been cache on your browser please clear cache with ctrl+f5

Comment: ok . just new information , i cleared the cache and everything seems ok :| i need to upload the whole webpage and test again, probably clear cache again . now i am just confused

Comment: as said before its been cache for test change you can you add version number end of your css file address and each time you change the css file for see new changes without caching just change number of version file in source

like tihs:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://anzalweb.ir/wp-content/themes/anzalweb-v2/css/style-min.css?v=2.0.4">

?v=2.0.4 do nothing it just force browser read new css file

Comment: just one more question . using version in CSS file is enough or do i have to use it in png and other files too ?

Comment: can No-store cache control meta help ? dose it apply to everything? including css and files? or just the html ?

Comment: css version is used for only css classes and codes in there, not files! you can use version trick for js too, my suggestion is if you using wordpress , install wp cache plugin for take more control in caching files and etc